# Can javascript get or set printer info?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, printing

Through Javascript (or jquery) is it possible to do one of the following...

1. Find out the current page size and orientation of the browser's print dialog.

OR

2. Set (or at least suggest) a page size and orientation to the browser's print dialog.

I have images of various sizes and dimensions, and I would like to provide a printable form which makes the best use of the selected page size.  I.e. I want to scale and or rotate the image so that it takes up as much of the page as possible.

Or is there a way to handle this in CSS?

Comment: I do not think this is possible in pure Javascript. You can only use window.print() which will show a printer dialog box. In this dialog box the user could change the page size and orientation, I think the only option you have is to ask the user what page size and orientation he/she is intending to print to and format the page accordingly.

Comment: CSS would be the way to go. In theory, you could use something like this:  `@media print and (orientation:portrait) {.myImage {-moz-transform:rotate(90deg); -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); transform:rotate(90deg);}}` to ensure that short, wide pictures always print in landscape orientation regardless of the user's print dialog settings. You might also want to put the pictures in a div with `page-break-inside: avoid;` set on it.

Comment: @DoctorDestructo Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but the browser just seems to always stick with it's most orientation and paper size regardless of what I have in the CSS.

Comment: @xtempore The point wasn't to change the browser's orientation setting, but to make the content fit the browser's orientation setting, whatever it might be. See my answer below for a proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is beyond the realm of JS as the print dialog is OS-specific.

However, the closest thing to a configuration would be [media queries in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) or the [`media` attribute of `<link>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link). Instead of suggesting page size and/or orientation, just adapt the page to look appropriate on print. This can also mean that the CSS on screen is totally different on print. Just make sure your HTML is created to adapt such.

Or better, provide a totally different page with totally different CSS for print. That way, you don't have to over-engineer that single page to look good on more than 1 media (and end up with spaghetti).

Comment: A print stylesheet is always recommended and should be used. Optionally you can also generate a PDF from your website with some libraries

Comment: I'm just trying to keep it as simple as possible for the user. I might just assume a portrait orientation and then rotate the image accordingly. Either that or use the PDF option, although I feel like that adds an extra step for the user.

Comment: @xtempore A special "print-friendly" page doesn't need an extra step. It only needs that special page to be opened in a hidden iframe, and calls `print()` immediately, which opens the print dialog. The PDF takes an extra step (displays the PDF) but treat it as having the user review the thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any way to target specific page sizes that works in print media, but you can make a landscape-oriented image rotate 90 degrees when the user is printing in portrait orientation. This works in Firefox (haven't tested others):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @media print {
        body {
          margin: 0;
        }
      }
      @media print and (orientation:portrait) {
        .landscapeImage {
          -moz-transform-origin: 200px 200px; /* set both values to half of image height */
          -ms-transform-origin: 200px 200px; /* set both values to half of image height */
          -webkit-transform-origin: 200px 200px; /* set both values to half of image height */
          transform-origin: 200px 200px; /* set both values to half of image height */
          -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
          -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
      }
      .landscapeImage { /* faux image */
        height: 400px;
        width: 600px;
        display: inline-block; /* not part of solution */
        box-sizing: border-box; /* not part of solution */
        border: 4px solid black; /* not part of solution */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="landscapeImage">
      Pretend this is an image
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Multi-page print jobs could potentially be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Thanks. It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome. For now I'll assume a portrait orientation (which most people will have as their default), and later on I might implement as PDF (although that has the downside of having to specify a page size - Letter or A4).